# SVG Background image not stretching horizontally cross-browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, cross-browser

I've been trying to place an SVG image as the background on a button to stretch horizontally whilst ignoring its aspect ratio.

Changes made to the SVG (pasted below) itself:

1. Doesn't have a height/width specified
2. Has a viewbox specified
3. Has preserveAspectRatio set to none

On the button CSS, I have set the background-size to **contain** as cover cuts off the image really badly. (Tried all variants, cover/contain/100%, etc.)

The issue I'm having is in chrome/internet explorer it works, the top/bottom of the SVG don't get clipped and the image will stretch the entire button width not preserving the aspect ratio however in **Firefox** it's behaving differently. With **contain** it will not cut the image off but it won't stretch horizontally (left to right).

I've even tried to modify the viewport attribute of the image to trick it into thinking that the SVG starts in a negative x-axis and ends on a few pixels after however the cutting off is so bad that it doesn't really help.

```
    background-image: -LocalPathToSvgHere-;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
```

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 320 56" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Potato</title>
    <desc>Potato</desc>
    <g id="R/Button-Label/CTA/Tertiary" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M0.5,17.5326192 C0.5,21.134829 0.5,21.2157139 0.5,24.3520124 C0.5,26.6893708 8.46597491,37.9348422 13.1090932,43.0525551 C15.4600591,45.6438241 39.4446053,47.5 57.9273753,47.5 C61.5631859,47.5 61.5631859,47.5 70.4221316,47.5 C81.5195636,47.5 81.5195636,47.5 96.3478064,47.5 C130.481265,47.5 130.481265,47.5 170.584021,47.5 C211.871513,47.5 211.871513,47.5 246.64488,47.5 C261.588767,47.5 261.588767,47.5 272.461326,47.5 C276.981557,47.5 276.981557,47.5 280.178606,47.5 C282.663173,47.5 282.663173,47.5 283.620992,47.5 C289.29903,47.5 310.091972,42.3446581 315.622765,39.5788135 C317.865301,38.4573635 319.081148,33.9095947 319.408162,26.9801828 C319.548303,24.0106156 319.522522,21.0230455 319.387874,17.3717289 C319.369797,16.8815236 319.313978,15.4726684 319.310575,15.3831616 C319.286097,14.7393679 319.275069,14.3534829 319.275069,14.079734 C319.275069,13.2081444 315.100704,11.0519411 308.117483,8.31092871 C306.935674,7.84705249 305.671625,7.3636301 304.302705,6.85069851 C302.771485,6.27695358 301.186152,5.69460903 299.214559,4.97880769 C298.762445,4.81466439 295.499718,3.63387159 294.649303,3.32388632 C291.339557,2.11744935 289.744311,1.49373751 289.135173,1.13418709 C288.051185,0.494350173 265.467574,0.360897195 229.046494,0.636848595 C221.616635,0.693142366 213.785139,0.764151284 205.094422,0.851775487 C201.231941,0.890718969 197.382255,0.931029217 192.721132,0.98094912 C191.820559,0.990594125 184.181903,1.07289388 182.226924,1.09363588 C174.94256,1.17092176 171.309266,1.2036018 169.616598,1.2036018 C165.570019,1.2036018 165.570019,1.2036018 156.624478,1.2036018 C145.229455,1.2036018 145.229455,1.2036018 128.93547,1.2036018 C89.0245372,1.2036018 88.9990727,1.2036018 29.5806702,1.2036018 C26.0586592,2.89740564 23.1029239,4.49572223 20.7144439,5.99744516 C18.2932873,7.51971305 11.5600641,11.361798 0.5,17.5326192 Z" id="Button-Colour" stroke="#EAE7EE" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Sidenote: *Would like to avoid the usage of post-page load js that calculates the width/sets it after the elements have loaded.*

=============================================================================

**Update - created a working example of the issue**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZgqpO

Open it in both chrome and firefox to see the issue.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element? Also please post you SVG code here (or the important parts thereof)

Comment: I mean in Firefox and in Chrome you can right click and inspect elements on a web page. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector) and [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)  The firefox one is better.

Comment: No off course at all, we only know what you tell us. your CSS `background-*` also seems to be wrong -- is that a PHP variable in there? You need to use the browser Inspector to see what's going on

Comment: Isn't that fixed in Firefox 68? Are you running that version?

Comment: I've just updated to Firefox 68, was running on 67 before but it doesn't appear to be fixed. If I set the background-size to contain. It works perfectly as I expect it to in both chrome/internet explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my FF browser, it works if you change `background-size: 100%` to `background-size: 100% 100%`. This property takes two arguments, `width` and `height`, and sets `height` to `auto` if not provided. I guess that, depending on the version, you may need to set `-moz-background-size`.

Answer (score 1):

First I've made a few changes to the svg you are using.

I've changed the viewBox from `viewBox="0 0 320 56"` to `viewBox="0 0 320 48"`. The actual viewBox is too tall leaving a empty gap beneath the "potato". In order to get it right I'm using the method `.getBBox`. This is returning the bounding box of the wrapping group and the returned value is looking like this:

```
SVGRect {x: 0.5, 
         y: 0.5008549094200134, 
         width: 319.0018005371094, 
         height: 46.9991455078125
}
```

I can use these values to build the viewBox, and what I get is:

```
viewBox = "0.5 0.5 319 47"
```

However I want to use a `stroke-width="3"` for the potato (it's just an example, you can use the value you want). If `stroke-width="3"` I would need a slightly bigger viewBox because I don't want the stroke to be cuted off. So I'm using `viewBox="0 0 320 48"`

If you are planing to use the image on different sizes of buttons the stroke will be scaled as well and you will get thicker or thinner strokes. Also since you are using `preserveAspectRatio="none"` the stroke may get irregular since it may be stretched differently on x and on y. The solution to this problem is using `vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'`

```js
console.log(theG.getBBox())
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 320 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="theG">
        <path d="M0.5,17.5326192 C0.5,21.134829 0.5,21.2157139 0.5,24.3520124 C0.5,26.6893708 8.46597491,37.9348422 13.1090932,43.0525551 C15.4600591,45.6438241 39.4446053,47.5 57.9273753,47.5 C61.5631859,47.5 61.5631859,47.5 70.4221316,47.5 C81.5195636,47.5 81.5195636,47.5 96.3478064,47.5 C130.481265,47.5 130.481265,47.5 170.584021,47.5 C211.871513,47.5 211.871513,47.5 246.64488,47.5 C261.588767,47.5 261.588767,47.5 272.461326,47.5 C276.981557,47.5 276.981557,47.5 280.178606,47.5 C282.663173,47.5 282.663173,47.5 283.620992,47.5 C289.29903,47.5 310.091972,42.3446581 315.622765,39.5788135 C317.865301,38.4573635 319.081148,33.9095947 319.408162,26.9801828 C319.548303,24.0106156 319.522522,21.0230455 319.387874,17.3717289 C319.369797,16.8815236 319.313978,15.4726684 319.310575,15.3831616 C319.286097,14.7393679 319.275069,14.3534829 319.275069,14.079734 C319.275069,13.2081444 315.100704,11.0519411 308.117483,8.31092871 C306.935674,7.84705249 305.671625,7.3636301 304.302705,6.85069851 C302.771485,6.27695358 301.186152,5.69460903 299.214559,4.97880769 C298.762445,4.81466439 295.499718,3.63387159 294.649303,3.32388632 C291.339557,2.11744935 289.744311,1.49373751 289.135173,1.13418709 C288.051185,0.494350173 265.467574,0.360897195 229.046494,0.636848595 C221.616635,0.693142366 213.785139,0.764151284 205.094422,0.851775487 C201.231941,0.890718969 197.382255,0.931029217 192.721132,0.98094912 C191.820559,0.990594125 184.181903,1.07289388 182.226924,1.09363588 C174.94256,1.17092176 171.309266,1.2036018 169.616598,1.2036018 C165.570019,1.2036018 165.570019,1.2036018 156.624478,1.2036018 C145.229455,1.2036018 145.229455,1.2036018 128.93547,1.2036018 C89.0245372,1.2036018 88.9990727,1.2036018 29.5806702,1.2036018 C26.0586592,2.89740564 23.1029239,4.49572223 20.7144439,5.99744516 C18.2932873,7.51971305 11.5600641,11.361798 0.5,17.5326192 Z"  stroke="#EAE7EE" fill="#FFFFFF" vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' stroke-width='3'></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Now I'm using the svg image as background for the button. For the demo I'm using data uri but you can use the external file.

Ive commented out the `border: none;` only because I wanted to show how the "potato" is covering the button.

Instead of `background-size: contain;` I'm using `background-size: 100%;`

I hope this is what you are asking.

```css
body {
  font: 32px sans-serif; color: #444;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 30%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  border: 0.5px dotted red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: none;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  /*border: none !important;*/
 
  /*background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/E46.svg");*/
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='-1.5 -.5 323 49' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cg %3E%3Cpath d='M0.5,17.5326192 C0.5,21.134829 0.5,21.2157139 0.5,24.3520124 C0.5,26.6893708 8.46597491,37.9348422 13.1090932,43.0525551 C15.4600591,45.6438241 39.4446053,47.5 57.9273753,47.5 C61.5631859,47.5 61.5631859,47.5 70.4221316,47.5 C81.5195636,47.5 81.5195636,47.5 96.3478064,47.5 C130.481265,47.5 130.481265,47.5 170.584021,47.5 C211.871513,47.5 211.871513,47.5 246.64488,47.5 C261.588767,47.5 261.588767,47.5 272.461326,47.5 C276.981557,47.5 276.981557,47.5 280.178606,47.5 C282.663173,47.5 282.663173,47.5 283.620992,47.5 C289.29903,47.5 310.091972,42.3446581 315.622765,39.5788135 C317.865301,38.4573635 319.081148,33.9095947 319.408162,26.9801828 C319.548303,24.0106156 319.522522,21.0230455 319.387874,17.3717289 C319.369797,16.8815236 319.313978,15.4726684 319.310575,15.3831616 C319.286097,14.7393679 319.275069,14.3534829 319.275069,14.079734 C319.275069,13.2081444 315.100704,11.0519411 308.117483,8.31092871 C306.935674,7.84705249 305.671625,7.3636301 304.302705,6.85069851 C302.771485,6.27695358 301.186152,5.69460903 299.214559,4.97880769 C298.762445,4.81466439 295.499718,3.63387159 294.649303,3.32388632 C291.339557,2.11744935 289.744311,1.49373751 289.135173,1.13418709 C288.051185,0.494350173 265.467574,0.360897195 229.046494,0.636848595 C221.616635,0.693142366 213.785139,0.764151284 205.094422,0.851775487 C201.231941,0.890718969 197.382255,0.931029217 192.721132,0.98094912 C191.820559,0.990594125 184.181903,1.07289388 182.226924,1.09363588 C174.94256,1.17092176 171.309266,1.2036018 169.616598,1.2036018 C165.570019,1.2036018 165.570019,1.2036018 156.624478,1.2036018 C145.229455,1.2036018 145.229455,1.2036018 128.93547,1.2036018 C89.0245372,1.2036018 88.9990727,1.2036018 29.5806702,1.2036018 C26.0586592,2.89740564 23.1029239,4.49572223 20.7144439,5.99744516 C18.2932873,7.51971305 11.5600641,11.361798 0.5,17.5326192 Z' id='Button-Colour' stroke='%23EAE7EE' fill='none' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' stroke-width='3' %3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center !important;
  width: 100%; 
}

p {
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Svg issue</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Body</p>
  <div>
    <button>Svg Button</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort you took to put this answer together. I've had a play about with what you've done here. I found that in firefox the button scales incorrectly and the top/bottom is still cut off. You can see this if you run the code snippet in firefox. Surprisingly another answer which mentions background-size: 100% 100%; seems to fix it. I hadn't tried that, had only done a single 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that the body width/height are specified using pixels, and not a responsive unit, like percentage etc.

Adjust your body's width and height to your desired width% and height%, and if necessary you could create a div to surround the svg and set a lower width/height there.

The percentages will prevent your svg from clipping when the screen width is less than 800px (width currently specified).

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is, my codepen that I've linked is kinda pointless. I'm using the SVG as a background-image and the css doesn't work the same way nor does it have css properties such as background-size etc. I think it's best I remove that codepen and try include one where the SVG is referenced via a URL on a buttons background-image.

Comment: Updated: with a proper codepen of the issue being recreated. When you open it in firefox you'll see what I mean. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZgqpO

Comment: @JARRRRG your codepen performs identically in both my firefox and chrome browsers. What version of FF/Chrome are you using? (I tested with FF 67.03 and 68 and Chrome 75 - the latest vsn)

Answer (score -1):

looks like you could just:

```
svg {
  width: fit-content;
  }
```